# I am having a problem in java programming. I am getting an error "column count doesn't match the value count at row 1"

Tags: java, mysql

Here's the code. I am unable to insert information into MySQL through netbeans. The source code is error free. However on clicking the button, I am receiving a dialog box saying

> column count doesn't match the value count at row 1

```
int z=Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
String w=jTextField2.getText();
int m=Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText());
String k=jTextField4.getText();
String y=jTextField5.getText();
String i=jTextField6.getText();

try
{
    Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
    Connection c;
    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dilshahiba","root","hope");
    Statement o=c.createStatement();
    String q;
    q = "Insert into hospital(PNO,Patient_Name,Age,Gender,Department,Doctor) values(z+w+m+k+y+i)";
    o.executeUpdate(q);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"BOOKED");
    o.close();
    c.close();
}
catch(HeadlessException e) {    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
} 
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {    
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
} 
 catch (SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
}
```

This is the first I am doing a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"Insert into hospital(PNO,Patient_Name,Age,Gender,Department,Doctor) values(z+w+m+k+y+i)";
```

You should not be specifying the values with a "+" between each variable. The values (not the variables) need to be separated by a comma the must be delimited properly.

An easier solution is to use a PreparedStatement to simplify the SQL.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO hospital (PNA, Patient_Name, Age, Gender, Department, Doctor) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

stmt.setString( 1, z );
stmt.setString( 2, w );
stmt.setInt( 3, m );
...
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

The basic idea is each "?" specifies a parameter and then the parameter gets replaced by the value you provide:

The PreparedStatement will then make sure the proper delimiters are used in the SQL as the parameters are replace.

Read the section from the JCBC tutorial on [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a java expert so my suggestion are related  to the SQL part

Your error is  related  to the fact thatb the number of columns in INTO clause  don't match the number of columns in Value clause

You must use comma for separate the values  content

```
Insert into hospital(PNO,Patient_Name,Age,Gender,Department,Doctor) 
    values  ('valuePNO','valuePatient_name','value_gender','value_dep', 'value_doc')
```

You have 6 columns in INTO clause  then you need 6 elements in value clause  ..

using +  you build just a value

you should check in you language for assign proper value the  value suggested

and you should also take a look how in java is possible use binding param for avoid the use of far in sql code  (avoiding in this way the risk for sqlinjection)

Comment: I'm no SQL expert, but I don't believe you can just specify the variables in the SQL string. I have always used a PreparedStatement when using variables.

Comment: @camickr  correct  ..    i have just  looked  at the sql format  .. not at the content .. answer  updated ..  with a string concat  (i'm not a java expert)   .. for pass the value

Comment: Although this is better than the other answer because you have no included the proper delimiters, it is still not the preferred way to do this. Don't just use string concatenation. It is too easy to make a mistake with delimiters and so on. Use the `PreparedStatment`.

Comment: @camickr  .. answer  uopdated .. with SQL part only and some suggestion for binding param   .. thanks for useful  suggestion  ..

Comment: (1-) this is your third guess. Specifying the "?" doesn't do anything unless you are actually using a PreparedStatement and you specify the values that should be replaced.